# Unsatisfied link error: no library file in java.library.path

Tags: java, c, bash, gcc, java-native-interface

I have a directory structure like this

```
.
--compile_c.sh
--compile_java.sh
--config.sh
--execute_java.sh
--run.sh
--src
  --ccode
    --jnitest_SimpleJNITest.h
    --rtm_simple.c
  --jnitest
    --SimpleJNITest.java
--lib
  --rtm_simple.so
--classes
  --SimpleJNITest.class
```

How do I correctly run `SimpleJNITest` when it has a `native` method that is fleshed out in `rtm_simple.c`?

Currently, I have defined

**config.sh**

```
targetDir="classes"
libDir="lib"
srcDir="src"
MainPackage="jnitest"
Main="SimpleJNITest"

ccodeDir="ccode"
cFileName="rtm_simple"

jdkDir="/home/user/local/java/jdk1.7.0_65"

mkdir -p "$targetDir"
mkdir -p "$libDir"
```

and am trying to run

**run.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

source compile_java.sh

javah -d "${srcDir}/${ccodeDir}" -cp "$targetDir" -jni "${MainPackage}.${Main}"

source compile_c.sh

source execute_java.sh
```

where

**compile_java.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

source config.sh

javac -d "$targetDir" -sourcepath "$srcDir" -cp "${targetDir}:${libDir}/*" "${srcDir}/${MainPackage}/${Main}.java"
```

**compile_c.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

source config.sh

cFile="${srcDir}/${ccodeDir}/${cFileName}.c"
soFile="${libDir}/${cFileName}.so"

gcc -g -shared -fpic -I "${jdkDir}/include" -I "${jdkDir}/include/linux" $cFile -o $soFile
```

**execute_java.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
source config.sh

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${libDir}"

java -cp "${targetDir}:${libDir}/*" "${MainPackage}.${Main}"
```

(also tried `java -Djava.library.path="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$libDir" -cp "${targetDir}:${libDir}/*" "${MainPackage}.${Main}"`)

**output**

```
$ ./run.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rtm_simple in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at jnitest.SimpleJNITest.main(SimpleJNITest.java:17)
```

Code:

**SimpleJNITest.java**

```
package jnitest;

public class SimpleJNITest{

    public static final int NOF_ITERATIONS = 100000;

    public native int nofAborts(int nofTransactions);

    public void test(){

        int nofAborts = nofAborts(NOF_ITERATIONS);
        System.out.println(String.format("successfully completed %d transactions and had to retry %d times",nofAborts));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("rtm_simple");
        new SimpleJNITest().test();
    }
}
```

(also tried using `System.loadLibary("rtm_simple.so");`)

**jnitest_SimpleJNITest.h**

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class jnitest_SimpleJNITest */

#ifndef _Included_jnitest_SimpleJNITest
#define _Included_jnitest_SimpleJNITest
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#undef jnitest_SimpleJNITest_NOF_ITERATIONS
#define jnitest_SimpleJNITest_NOF_ITERATIONS 100000L
/*
* Class:     jnitest_SimpleJNITest
* Method:    nofAborts
* Signature: (I)I
*/
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_jnitest_SimpleJNITest_nofAborts
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**rtm_simple.c**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "jnitest_SimpleJNITest.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_jnitest_SimpleJNITest_nofAborts(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint nof_iterations){
    volatile int abort_counter = 0;
    volatile int i = 0;
    while (i < nof_iterations) {
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "xbegin 1f" /*1f: local label 1, look forward to find first*/
                :"+rm"(i) /*artificial dependency to prevent re-ordering*/
        ); 

        ++i;

        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "xend\n\t"
            "jmp 2f\n" /*not aborted ==> jump to local label 2*/
            "1:\n\t" /*local label 1 (jumped to when transaction is aborted)*/
            :"+rm"(abort_counter) /*artificial dependency*/
            :"rm"(i) /*artificial dependency*/
        );

        ++abort_counter;

        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "2:" /*local label 2 (jumped to when transactoin is NOt aborted)*/
            :"+rm"(abort_counter) /*artificial dependency*/
            :"rm"(i) /*artificial dependency*/
        );
    }

    if(i != nof_iterations) return -1;
    return abort_counter;
}
```

Comment: @mko Thank you. But that one is using ``cc``, same as the tutorial I've tried to follow, https://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips-100035/148-jni/1378-simple-example-of-using-the-java-native-interface.html . I'm using ``gcc``, and gcc doesn't have a ``-G`` flag. If you read my post, you'll actually notice I already tried the ``-Djava.library.path`` way the page you linked to suggests.

Comment: @mko ``Error: Could not find or load main class recipeNo001.HelloWorld``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify a file name, you need to use [`System.load(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load-java.lang.String-), and not the [`System.loadLibrary(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary-java.lang.String-) method. `loadLibrary` transforms the specified name in a platform-dependent manner.  On your system, a `lib` prefix and `.so` suffix is probably added, but this means no matter how you call `loadLibrary`, it won't be able to load a file called `rtm_simple.so` even if it is located on the library search path.  Or put differently, if you do want to use `loadLibrary`, you need to rename the file to `librtm_simple.so`.

You can see the paths the JVM uses if you run it under `strace -fF`.

Comment: I do not want to use ``System.load`` because that one requires an absolute path. However, you were right about the ``lib`` prefix. so if I change ``compile.sh`` s.t. ``soFile="${libDir}/lib${cFileName}.so"``, it works. Thank you. Want to adapt your answer to include this information more explicitly?

Comment: well spotted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you put your System.loadLibrary() in a static block in the SimpleJNITest class. You might need to be more explicit with the creation of the SimpleJNITest object in main.

```
public class SimpleJNITest{
public static final int NOF_ITERATIONS = 100000;
    static {
              System.loadLibrary("rtm_simple");
            }
    <blah blah blah>

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleJNITest simple = new SimpleJNITest();
        simple.text();
    }
}
```