# String manipulation in makefiles

Tags: makefile

I've replaced my many `.sh` files from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196942/unsatisfied-link-error-no-library-file-in-java-library-path) with a makefile, of sorts. I don't know much about makefiles, admittedly, but this seems to work:

```
MainPackage=jnitest
Main=SimpleJNITest
cFileName=rtm_simple

targetDir=classes
libDir=lib
srcDir=src

jdkDir="/home/user/local/java/jdk1.7.0_65"
java="$(jdkDir)/bin/java"
javah="$(jdkDir)/bin/javah"
javac="$(jdkDir)/bin/javac"

JAVAC_FLAGS=-d "$(targetDir)" -sourcepath "$(srcDir)" -cp "$(targetDir):$(libDir)/*"
JAVAH_FLAGS=-d "$(ccodeDir)" -cp "$(targetDir)" -jni
JAVA_FLAGS=-Djava.library.path="$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH):$(libDir)" -cp "$(targetDir):$(libDir)/*"

ccodeDir=$(srcDir)/ccode
CC=gcc
CC_FLAGS=-g -shared -fpic -I "$(jdkDir)/include" -I "$(jdkDir)/include/linux"


cFile="$(ccodeDir)/$(cFileName).c"
soFile="$(libDir)/lib$(cFileName).so"

dirs:
    mkdir -p "$(targetDir)"
    mkdir -p "$(libDir)"

java: dirs
    $(javac) $(JAVAC_FLAGS) "$(srcDir)/$(MainPackage)/$(Main).java"

header:
    $(javah) $(JAVAH_FLAGS) "$(MainPackage).$(Main)"

c:
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $(cFile) -o $(soFile)

all:
    $(MAKE) java
    $(MAKE) header
    $(MAKE) c

run:
    $(java) $(JAVA_FLAGS) "$(MainPackage).$(Main)"

clean:
    rm -rf classes
    rm -rf lib
    rm -f $(ccodeDir)/$(MainPackage)_$(Main).h
```

My problem, now, lies with `MainPackage=jnitest`.

So long as `MainPackage` is a single word, everything is fine.

However, when it is not, I'll be needing it once in slash notation for

```
$(javac) $(JAVAC_FLAGS) "$(srcDir)/$(MainPackage)/$(Main).java"
```

and once in dot notation for

```
$(java) $(JAVA_FLAGS) "$(MainPackage).$(Main)"
```

In bash, you could do something like

```
MainPackage_slashed=$(echo "$MainPackage" | tr '.' '/')
```

How do I insert one such transformation into a makefile?

Comment: FYI, you never want to use quotes in your simple path variable assignments like `jdkDir="/home/user/local/java/jdk1.7.0_65"`.  Make treats quotes just like any other character: they're not special at all.  So when you use `jdkDir` the quotes are preserved: `"$(jdkDir)/include"` expands to `""/home/user/local/java/jdk1.7.0_65"/include"` which is the opposite of what you want.  _Only_ include quotes in command lines, never in make variables that represent simple files or directories.  Ditto for `java`, `javah`, `javac`, `cFile`, `soFile`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the `subst` function, see [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html).

Example:

```
foo=x.y.z
bar=$(subst .,/,$(foo))
$(info $(bar))
```

prints `x/y/z`.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [`shell` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html#Shell-Function) in your Makefile like this:

```
MainPackage_slashed := $(shell echo "$(MainPackage)" | tr '.' '/')
```

Comment: Thank you.. ``MainPackage_slashed := $(shell echo "$(MainPackage)" | tr '.' '/')``, actually. Could you edit your post accordingly? I'd have done it myself, but "edits must be  at least 6 characters long".

Comment: Well, this does the job, but spawns new processes and depends on the environment providing `tr` -- why not use builtin `make` functions?

Comment: Yes I agree that for this simple string replace built-in function `subst` is better choice. However I am keeping this answer for general purpose when calling an external shell command is the only way to go.